# Problems with sum of user-inputted array elements

Tags: c, arrays, int, user-input, fgets

I'd like to apologize for the long post, and mostly useless stuff in my post and code, but I'd like to be as clear as possible.

My problem is a very basic one:

> You are given an array of integers of size N. You need to print the sum of the elements of the array. 
>   The first line of the input consists of an integer N. The next line contains N space-separated integers describing the array.
>   Sample input:

```
5  
1000000001 1000000002 1000000003 1000000004 1000000005
```

I usuallly ask for the n with a scanf, then do:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  scanf("%d", &a[i]);
```

But that is for numbers on separate lines.
Or I could do something like

```
scanf("%d %d %d", &a[0], &a[1], &a[2]);
```

But I'd have to know how many elements there will be before the execution of the program.

So I found a function online, `parseString`, which I used to get each number as an element of an array of strings and then I converted them element by element into an array of ints in my main function.

Here's the code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYheV.jpg

Which appeared to work, but when submitting the problem on www.hackerrank.com (A Very Big Sum), this appeared:

```
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:937:0,
                 from solution.c:3:
In function 'fgets',
    inlined from 'main' at solution.c:42:3:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:261:2: warning: call to '__fgets_chk_warn' declared with attribute warning: fgets called with bigger size than length of destination buffer
  return __fgets_chk_warn (__s, __bos (__s), __n, __stream);
  ^
```

I don't exactly understand how `parseString` works, but I got it to the point where I could use it to convert the array of strings to an array of ints.
The problem I understand hackerrank has, is with the buffer of the first fgets function.

Finally, I'd like to know what the easiest thing to do would be, to just get the space-separated numbers into an array.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What are these quotes around  `<` ???

Comment: What exactly are you expecting from '<' to do ??

Comment: It was an error when posting the question, removed the quotes!

Comment: @Putridul To mark a question resolved, you just need to accept an answer. There's no need to put [SOLVED] into the title of your question. Glad you found useful information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scanf("%d", &n);
for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &x);
    sum += x;
}
```

Doesn't work for you? Why?

Comment: It did work when I tried it now, thank you very much! I had some problems understanding exactly how scanf works.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0;i'<'n;i++) // i<n should be there not '<'(as this wont work).
scanf("%d", &a[i]);
```

And this won't take input on separate lines until you press `enter` you can press `space` between numbers instead.

And seeing size of your input you should use `long` or `long long`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't scanf would work like that with spaces.